# How to add an icon in correct size before text

Tags: html, icons

I want to include some customized images as icons before a text but I don't know of to set the icon size accoordilyngly to the size of the text.

EXAMPLE

<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/phone.png"Escríbenos por WhatsApp

Please see images

[image: This is how is looking]

[image: This is how it should look]

If possible please give me the html version of the code since I'm just started learning CSS

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+responsive+icon+before+text+in+button+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: not a proper question

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
img {  
    height: 50px;  
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```